# How does openAM handle an authentication request?

Tags: openam

I started studying openAM recently and need to go deep into its infrastructure.

I have learned that openAM provides some authentication APIs such as

```
Post: http://mywebsite/openam/json/authenticate
headers: X-OpenAM-Username:xxx  ,  X-OpenAM-Password:xxx
```

Basically I want to learn more about how openAM handles such a request, where is the controller? how does it validate the username and password? Can anyone give a hint where to start in openAM's [source](https://github.com/OpenRock/OpenAM) ?

Comment: Which version are you using? Implementation of REST API varies across OpenAM versions.

Comment: Hi. I am using 13.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the privilege of having access to the OpenAM/AM source code, then you could start to look at AuthenticationServiceV1 and the various RESTAuth*CallbackHandler classes to get a closer look at the REST side of things.

If you are interested in the authentication framework in its all glory, then AMLoginContext, AuthContext, LoginState and AMLoginModule are the classes you should take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [OpenAM 13 Developer's Guide - Using the REST API](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/dev-guide/chap-client-dev#sec-rest) at first.

If you want to know the implementation and behaviour of REST API, please check the OpenAM debug logs, read [source code of OpenAM REST Services](https://github.com/OpenRock/OpenAM/tree/master/openam-rest) and attach a debugger by using IDE.

Answer (score 0):

you can get token value after posting below REST API

```
Post: http://mywebsite/openam/json/authenticate
headers: X-OpenAM-Username:xxx  ,  X-OpenAM-Password:xxx
```

After that a list of List of REST API provided by openAM
 you need to add header value for every request

"iplanetDirectoryPro"  = "Received token value"